# Stack Exchanges sites offline

Tags: support

Are Stack Overflow, Serverfault and other Stack Exchanges sites down ? I get this when trying to access:

[image]

Comment: @martijn, are they ?

Comment: I'm seeing loads of problems everywhere, not everyone sees them.

Comment: @PedroLobito Yes they are.

Comment: Confirmation: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/733677041959219201

Comment: Why do we do this little dance every time SO goes down?

Comment: How is the meta not down too?

Comment: @Shadow, seems like meta on another servers

Comment: meta.stackexchange.com is offline (522) though.

Comment: @Will - I guess a lot of SO users don't actually follow StackExchange Status on Twitter (or can't access it at work).

Comment: @Will because nobody can get their work done.

Comment: Seem to be working now.

Comment: @BSMP: They also have a tendency to spend time investigating the issue before announcing that there is, in fact, an issue, as any reasonable support channel would do, by which time meta would already have been flooded with these questions.

Comment: @BoltClock - True. On the other hand, there almost certainly would have been a lot of tweets from other folks saying they couldn't reach SO, even if it hadn't been confirmed by the Status account yet.

Comment: @BSMP: I suppose it takes more than a few clicks to get to "tweets mentioning StackStatus"

Comment: @Will, because we like dancing. An outage is our only chance to get a nice waltz in during the work day.

Comment: This is basically, how to get free reputation? Ask why SO is down when it's down ^^

Comment: @Carlos2W it's meta. who cares.

Comment: @Carlos2W There's no reputation gained or lost on meta. It's tied to your main site reputation.

Answer (score 11):

It was down and now it is up. It was because of CloudFlare's connection with Stack Exchange sites. Was confirmed in [StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/733677041959219201):

[image]

Let's get back to giving to the community. :)

---

Update:

[image]